# Pointers to different instances of one templated function guaranteed to compare unequal?

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Is it safe to assume that two function pointers, that point to different instances of one templated function, will compare unequal?
Even if the templated function does not use the template parameter(s) at all and thus does the exact same thing in every case?

For example the following works fine on my compiler but I'm not sure if it does on any other:

```
class TypeChecker
{
public:
    template< typename T > static void foo( void )
    {}
    template< typename T > static void setType( void )
    { s_fooPtr = &foo< T >; }
    template< typename T > static bool checkType( void )
    { return ( s_fooPtr == &foo< T > ); }
private:
    static void ( * s_fooPtr )( void );
};

void ( * TypeChecker::s_fooPtr )( void ) = 0;

int main( void )
{
    TypeChecker::setType< char >();
    TypeChecker::checkType< char >();           // true
    TypeChecker::checkType< unsigned char >();  // false
    TypeChecker::checkType< signed char >();    // false
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**When will two pointer compare equal?**

According to 5.10/1:

> The == (equal to) and the != (not equal to) operators have the same
>   semantic restrictions, conversions, and result type as the relational
>   operators except for their lower precedence and truth-value result. [
>   Note: `a<b
>   == c<d` is true whenever `a<b` and `c<d` have the same truth-value. —end note ] Pointers of the same type (after pointer conversions) can be
>   compared for equality. Two pointers of the same type compare equal if
>   and only if they are both null, **both point to the same function,** or
>   both represent the same address (3.9.2).

**Are `foo<int>()` and `foo<char>()` the same function?**

According to 14.4/1:

> Two template-ids refer to the same class or function if
>
> - their template-names, operator-function-ids, or literal-operator-ids refer to the same template and
> - **their corresponding type template-arguments are the same type** and
> - their corresponding non-type template arguments of integral or enumeration type have identical values
>     and
> - their corresponding non-type template-arguments of pointer type refer to the same external object or
>     function or are both the null pointer value and
> - their corresponding non-type template-arguments of pointer-to-member type refer to the same class
>     member or are both the null member pointer value and
> - their corresponding non-type template-arguments of reference type refer to the same external object
>     or function and
> - their corresponding template template-arguments refer to the same template.

So apparently `foo<int>()` and `foo<char>()` are not the same function.

So `&foo<int>()` and `&foo<char>()` should not compare equal, whatever optimization is made.

---

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by @SergeDundich in the comment, 14.4/1 used `if` instead `if and only if`, which gives **no** guarantee whether `foo<int>()` and `foo<char>()` are the same function or not. In other parts of the specification, `if and only if` is used a lot.

I didn't find any clarification to this in the specification. However, in the examples, I can find this:

> ```
> template<class T, void(*err_fct)()> class list { /* ... */ };
> list<int,&error_handler1> x1;
> list<int,&error_handler2> x2;
> list<int,&error_handler2> x3;
> list<char,&error_handler2> x4;
> ```
>
> declares x2 and x3 to be of the same type. Their type **differs** from the
>   types of x1 and x4.

---

**EDIT2:**

`if` is used instead of `if and only if` as this situation exists: (Example from 14.5.7/2)

```
template<class T> struct Alloc { /* ... */ };
template<class T> using Vec = vector<T, Alloc<T>>;
Vec<int> v; // same as vector<int, Alloc<int>> v;
```

`Vec<int>` and `vector<int, Alloc<int>>` have a lot of differences, but still the same type.

However, as to the case of `foo<int>()` and `foo<char>()`, their signatures are different. The different signatures should render them different functions.

Thanks to @JohannesSchaub-litb .

Comment: What about "functions" in 3.9.2? That wording somehow implies a function is an object with an address.

Comment: @fefe: "Two template-ids refer to the same class or function **if**" But not "if and only if". Did you note that? IMO That is very important. And IMO your conclusion that "`foo<int>()` and `foo<char>()` are not the same function" is wrong. They obviously not required by the standard to be the same function but your quotes doesn't prove that they required to be **not the same function**.

Comment: @sharptooth: In 3.9.2/2, pointers are divided into `object pointer type` and `function pointer type`. Object pointer type is defined as "the type of **a pointer to** void or **a pointer to** an object type is called an object pointer type.", however "The type of a pointer that can **designate** a function is called a function pointer type." Seems that the specification is avoiding the use of "pointer to" for function pointer. And latter on, only object pointer type is said to `represents either the address of a byte in memory (1.7) or a null pointer (4.10).`.

Comment: @SergeDundich: Will put your comment in the answer. It's true that the specification used "if and only if" a lot.

Comment: For example, `template<typename T> using A = B<T>`. `A<int>` and `B<int>` can refer to the same class. Still the *template-name* in both cases does not refer to the same template (so the "if" instead of "if and only if" is important). However, the type that the alias template resolves to will refer to the same class by 14.5.7 and 14.4/1.

Comment: However it is clear that the spec requires both to be different functions (it's assumed everywhere, for example at 14.5.6.1p2). The description of specializations and names of them probably could be taken to prove that (I haven't tried). So the addresses are still required to be different. Note that in particular their *signatures* are different. A signature is *the* ID of a function or function template. If it is different, the functions are different. If it is the same, the functions are the same.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: In you example, I think the do refer to the sample template `B`, though the template names are different. I'll check the signature part.

Comment: @fefe In the last example of 14.4/1 an earlier draft (the one before the FDIS) said that using `A`, it is equivalent to `B`, but that was changed in the FDIS because that's not how it works (so instead of making `T` a template-template parameter of `X`, they made it a type parameter, and passed `Y<int>` and `Z<int>` instead of `Y` and `Z` respectively). The one template-name in `A<int>` is `A` and it does not refer to the template referred to by template-name `B` in `B<int>`.

Comment: @fefe: "**or** both represent the same address" IMO this looks like a key part to me. Even though two functions may be different they still may represent the same address. It seems that the function pointer is not required to represent any address but on the other hand I don't see anything that **denies** the function pointer to represent some address (which it does in reality as we all know).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Got it.

Comment: @Serge it was pointed out to me that the paragraph may have been written in the assumption that functions cannot have addresses (other paragraphs, for example 5.3.1p3 show similar wording - instead of saying "address of the designated object or function", it says "address of the designated object or a pointer to the designated function").

Comment: @SergeDundich: They can (and do) represent addresses. But IMHO, as function pointers are not intended to take addresses (only "designate" functions. Though in practice, addresses are used to designate functions), the part "both represent the same address" should not be applied function pointers

Comment: @fefe: <<the part "both represent the same address" should not be applied function pointers>> Why? If the function pointers **do** represent addresses (though not required or even mentioned in the standard **but not denied also**) why the part "both represent the same address" cannot be applied to them for those implementations for which they do represent addresses?

Comment: @SergeDundich: Because for the specification, they only designate functions. How they designate function is implementation detail, and should not affect the specification. (This behavior is not implementation defined).