# Can a compiler perform global optimization on similar template classe member function?

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, compiler-construction

I’m creating a new container. One of its template parameters is its initial capacity. As a result, creating instances with different initial capacities will result in the compiler generating the same code for each templated class.

```
MyVector<3> firstVector;
MyVector<4> secondVector;
...
if (firstVector.empty() && secondVector.empty())
{
   ...
}
```

This snippet would cause the compiler to generate `empty()` for both classes. Can a compiler eliminate this redudancy?

Comment: Why is the initial capacity a template paramtere? Just wondering, the standard containers seem to do fine without it and I can't see it enabling any optimizations (I take *initial* as implying the container can grow freely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `empty()` will perhaps be very simple and the compiler will be able to inline it. What if is cannot be inlined? The compiler can do any kind of merging but it must do it in such way that distinct functions have distinct addresses:

```
&MyVector<3>::empty() != &MyVector<4>::empty()
```

Visual C++ 10 can exhibit non-standard behavior here depending on linker settings - with some settings it will detect such functions and just merge them thus violating the Standard. I haven't seen it ever doing such elimination in a Standard-compliant way.

Comment: I think that's a valid optimization. Two pointers to functions must compare unequal if they have the same type, but point to different functions. But your function types differ. (You're right about the general case of MSVC10; `/Gy /OPT:ICF` can cause this.)

Comment: What part of the standard says these must have unique addresses? 1.8-6 indicates objects must have unique addresses, but what says functions must (they aren't objects)?

Comment: @edA-qa mort-ora-y: Here's a question about that http://stackoverflow.com/q/8667515/57428

Comment: BTW, even _if_ `&MyVector<3>::empty() != &MyVector<4>::empty()`, direct calls (not via pointer) may still be merged. E.g. `&MyVector<4>::empty()` could be a simple `JMP` to `&MyVector<3>::empty()`, and current optimizers can optimize such call chains.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, compiler does not eliminate this. Consider following example:

```
template<size_t CAPACITY>
class MyVector {
...
public:
  bool empty() const { static int i = CAPACITY; return ...; }
};
```

In above case, you can see that every `MyVector<N>::empty()` has to be unique, because `static int i` should be exclusive to the function. Even if the `static int` is not present, compiler will always assume its possibility. So, if a copy of `empty()` would be generated, it will be generated for all versions.

I am answering theoretically. Not aware if a compiler have some practical optimization technique, which would overcome such things.

However, if your `MyVector` looks like this:

```
template<size_t CAPACITY, typename T>
class MyVector : public vector<T>
{
  // using vector<T>::empty;
};
```

Then, only one copy would be generated.

Comment: This argument does not hold. You demonstrated a case in which the merge would violate the Standard, but this does not refute the general case.

Comment: @MatthieuM., the other case of address not being equal was discussed in other answer, so I avoided repeating that. Moreover, my "assumption" is theoretical.

Comment: I agree with @MatthieuM. The concise version of the question is "Must a compiler emit multiple copies of a class template method, if that method does not depend on the template parameters?" With that phrasing, it's clear why this argument doesn't hold.

Comment: @MSalters: Actually, that is not what I meant. If the method was: `bool empty() const { static unsigned i = 0; ++i; return ...; }` it would still be *un*-foldable, because of the local static.

Comment: @MatthieuM: That would be a correct counter-example (doesn't depend on template parameter, yet it does have a unique identity).

Answer (score 0):

Does the empty() method use the template parameter?  If not, you can factor it into a non-templated base class from which the templated class inherits.